# Как зашифровать многострочный текстовый документ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, шифрование

выскакивает такая ошибка: TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 7 found моя программа

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Генератор зашифрованных сообщений")
root.geometry("1500x1080")
lbl_in = Label(root, text="Введите исходное сообщение:", font=50, width=24)
lbl_key = Label(root, text="Введите ключевое слово:", font=50, width=20)
lbl_in2 = Label(root, text="Введите сообщение для расшифровки:", font=50, width=35)
lbl_key2 = Label(root,text="Введите ключевое слово:", font=50, width=24)

def file():
    f=open("Текст.txt","r")
    return(f.read())
def file_readlines():
    f=open("Текст2.txt","r")
    return(f.readlines())

#программа для шифра Цезаря
def shifr_cezarya(message,key):
    result=[]
    k=0
    alf = ['А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т',
            'У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я']
    alf2 = ['а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т',
            'у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я']
    for i,txt in enumerate(message):
        if txt.isupper():
            if txt!=' ':
                mes=alf.index(txt)
                ky=alf2.index(key)
                y=(mes+ky)%33
                result.append(alf[y])
            else:
                k+=1
                result.append(' ')
        else:
            if txt!=' ':
                mes=alf2.index(txt)
                ky=alf2.index(key)
                y=(mes+ky)%33
                result.append(alf2[y])
            else:
                k+=1
                result.append(' ')
    return ''.join(result)
def deshifr_cezarya(message,key):
    result=[]
    k=0
    alf = ['А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т',
            'У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я']
    alf2 = ['а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т',
            'у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я']
    for i,txt in enumerate(message):
        if txt.isupper():
            if txt!=' ':
                mes=alf.index(txt)
                ky=alf2.index(key)
                y=(mes-ky)%33
                result.append(alf[y])
            else:
                k+=1
                result.append(' ')
        else:
            if txt!=' ':
                mes=alf2.index(txt)
                ky=alf2.index(key)
                y=(mes-ky)%33
                result.append(alf2[y])
            else:
                k+=1
                result.append(' ')
    return "".join(result)

def result_cezar(root, message, key):
    lbl_out = Label(root,text="Зашифрованное слово:",font=50)
    txt3 = Entry(root,width=40)
    operation = shifr_cezarya(message, key)
    txt3.insert(0,operation)#Этот метод вставляет заданный элемент с заданным индексом(здесь индекс равен 0, то есть текст будет вставлен на первое место)!
    lbl_out.place(x=295,y=135)
    txt3.place(x=295,y=170)

def result_decezar(root,message,key):
    lbl_out = Label(root,text="Расшировано слово:",font=50)
    txt = Entry(root,width=40)
    operation = deshifr_cezarya(message,key)
    txt.insert(0,operation)
    lbl_out.place(x=1226,y=120)
    txt.place(x=1230,y=165)

#программа для шифра Виженера
def shifr_vizhenera(message,key):
    result=[]
    k=0
    alf = ['А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т',
           'У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я']
    alf2 = ['а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т',
            'у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я']
    for i,txt in enumerate(message):
        if txt.isupper():
            if txt!=' ':
                mes=alf.index(txt)
                ky=alf2.index(key[(i-k)%len(key)])
                y=(mes+ky)%33
                result.append(alf[y])
            else:
                k+=1
                result.append(' ')
        else:
            if txt!=' ':
                mes=alf2.index(txt)
                ky=alf2.index(key[(i-k)%len(key)])
                y=(mes+ky)%33
                result.append(alf2[y])
            else:
                k+=1
                result.append(' ')
    return "".join(result)

def deshifr_vizhenera(message,key):
    result=[]
    k=0
    alf = ['А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т',
           'У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я']
    alf2 = ['а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т',
            'у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я']
    for i,txt in enumerate(message):
        if txt.isupper():
            if txt!=' ':
                txt=alf.index(txt)
                ky=alf2.index(key[(i-k)%len(key)])
                y=(txt-ky)%33
                result.append(alf[y])
            else:
                k+=1
                result.append(' ')
        else:
            if txt!=' ':
                txt=alf2.index(txt)
                ky=alf2.index(key[(i-k)%len(key)])
                y=(txt-ky)%33
                result.append(alf2[y])
            else:
                k+=1
                result.append(' ')
    return "".join(result)


def result_vizhener(root, message, key):
    lbl_out = Label(root, text="Зашифрованное слово:", font=50)
    txt4 = Entry(root,width=40)
    operation2 = shifr_vizhenera(message, key)
    txt4.insert(0, operation2)
    lbl_out.place(x=295,y=195)
    txt4.place(x=295,y=225)

def result_devizhener(root,message,key):
    lbl_out = Label(root, text="Расшифровано слово:", font=50)
    txt5 = Entry(root,width=40)
    operation3 = deshifr_vizhenera(message,key)
    txt5.insert(0,operation3)
    lbl_out.place(x=1227,y=190)
    txt5.place(x=1230,y=235)

def shifr_file(file_message, key):
    result=[]
    k=0
    alf = ['А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т',
           'У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я']
    alf2 = ['а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т',
            'у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я']
    file_message=file_message.replace("\n","")
    for i,txt in enumerate(file_message):
        if txt.isupper():
            if txt!=' ':
                mes=alf.index(txt)
                ky=alf2.index(key)
                y=(mes+ky)%33
                result.append(alf[y])
            else:
                k+=1
                result.append(' ')
        else:
            if txt!=' ':
                mes=alf2.index(txt)
                ky=alf2.index(key)
                y=(mes+ky)%33
                result.append(alf2[y])
            else:
                k+=1
                result.append(' ')
    return ''.join(result)

def shifr_file_readlines(file_message, key):
    s1=''
    alf2 = ['а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т',
            'у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я']
    key=alf2.index(key)
    for c in file_message:
        if ord(c) in range(ord('а'), ord('я')+1): # если это символ а-я
            s1 += chr(ord('а') + (ord(c) - ord('а') + key)%33)
        elif ord(c) in range(ord('А'), ord('Я')+1): # если это символ А-Я
            s1 += chr(ord('А') + (ord(c) - ord('А') + key)%33)
        else: # иначе просто дописываем этот символ
            s1 += c
    return s1

def result_file(root, file_message, key):
    lbl_out = Label(root,text="Файл зашифрован", font=50)
    k=shifr_file(t,key)
    f=open("Текст.txt","w")
    f.write(str(k))
    f.close()
    lbl_out.place(x=460,y=270)

def result_file_readlines(root,file_message,key):
    lbl_out = Label(root,text="Файл зашифрован", font=50)
    f=open("Текст2.txt","w")
    f.write(shifr_file_readlines(file_message,key))
    f.close()
    lbl_out.place(x=460,y=320)

t=file()
p=file_readlines()

tp1=StringVar()
tp2=StringVar()
tp3=StringVar()
tp4=StringVar()

txt1 = Entry(root,textvariable=tp1,width=40)
txt2 = Entry(root,textvariable=tp2,width=40)
txt3 = Entry(root,textvariable=tp3,width=40)
txt4 = Entry(root,textvariable=tp4,width=40)

btn_cezar = Button(root, text="Зашифровать шифром Цезаря",command=lambda: result_cezar(root,tp1.get(),tp2.get()),
             font="Calibri 15", height=2,width=28,bg="green")
btn_vizhener = Button(root, text="Зашифровать шифром Виженера",command=lambda: result_vizhener(root,tp1.get(),tp2.get()),
              font="Calibri 15",height=2,width=28,bg="green")
btn_file_cezar = Button(root, text="Зашифровать файл шифром Цезаря",command=lambda: result_file(root,t,tp2.get()),
              font="Calibri 15",height=2,width=45,bg="green")
btn_filelines_cezar = Button(root, text="Зашифровать многострочный файл шифром Цезаря",command=lambda: result_file_readlines(root,p,tp2.get()),
              font="Calibri 15",height=2,width=45,bg="green")
btn_devizhener = Button(root, text="Расшифровать слово методом Виженера",command=lambda: result_devizhener(root,tp3.get(),tp4.get()),
              font="Calibri 15",height=2,width=35,bg="green")

btn_decezar = Button(root, text="Расшифровать слово методом Цезаря",command=lambda: result_decezar(root,tp3.get(),tp4.get()),
              font="Calibri 15",height=2,width=35,bg="green")

lbl_in.place(x=0,y=0)
txt1.place(x=0,y=30)
lbl_key.place(x=0,y=60)
txt2.place(x=0,y=90)
lbl_in2.place(x=840,y=0)
txt3.place(x=860,y=30)
lbl_key2.place(x=840,y=60)
txt4.place(x=860,y=90)
btn_cezar.place(x=0,y=130)
btn_vizhener.place(x=0,y=195)
btn_file_cezar.place(x=0,y=250)
btn_filelines_cezar.place(x=0,y=300)
btn_devizhener.place(x=860,y=191)
btn_decezar.place(x=860,y=125)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 7 found` - функция ord() ожидает символ, но передается строка, размером 7 элементов

Comment: как можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Замените

```
txt != ' '
```

в первой проверке на

```
txt in alf
```

во второй на

```
txt in alf2
```

И под `else` делайте

```
result.append(txt)
```

Comment: К сожалению, с файлом ничего не происходит(

Comment: @Tiranich вы в функцию передаёте список строк из файла или сам файл?

Comment: я передаю содержимое файла в виде нескольких строк, если я внесу их в виде одной сплошной строки без пробелов, то обратно в многострочную не могу перевести

Answer (score 0):

Для шифровки файлов шифром Цезаря вы можете использовать следующий метод:

```py
def Caesar(s, key):
  s1 = ''
  for c in s:
    if ord(c) in range(ord('а'), ord('я')+1): # если это символ а-я
      s1 += chr(ord('а') + (ord(c) - ord('а') + key)%33)
    elif ord(c) in range(ord('А'), ord('Я')+1): # если это символ А-Я
      s1 += chr(ord('А') + (ord(c) - ord('А') + key)%33)
    else: # иначе просто дописываем этот символ
      s1 += c
  return s1

s = open('file.txt').read() # читаем из файла в строку
open('encoded.txt', 'w').write(Caesar(s,3)) # записываем в другой файл уже закодированный текст
```

Недостаток именно этого подхода заключается в том, что буква Ё по алфавиту мало того, что идёт в конце, так ещё и после буквы Ѐ, поэтому в данном случае буква Ё не шифруется вовсе. Но вы можете использовать подход, изменив само преобразование букв на то, которое вам удобно.
Символ переноса строки `\n` также является символом строки, а т.к. к нему не применяется сдвиг, он остаётся на своём месте, и все переносы соблюдаются

Comment: в отдельной программе это сработало, но в моей основной нет, выскакивает такая ошибка: TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 7 found

Comment: @Tiranich это связано с тем, что вы передаёте функции не строку, а список строк. Если вы пытаетесь передать аргументом `open('file.txt').readlines()`, замените `readlines()` на `read()`. Другой вариант решения, если `s` - список строк, а не строка, передать аргументом `''.join(s)`

Comment: У меня просто удаляется содержимое файла((

Comment: @Tiranich добавьте в свой вопрос полный код

Comment: добавил программу

Answer (score 0):

Простенькая реализация Цезаря.

```
def shifr_file_readlines(text: str, key: int = 13) -> str:
    ru_lower = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
    ru_upper = ru_lower.upper()

    def get_shift(alp: str, c: str, key: int) -> str:
        i = (alp.index(c) + key) % len(alp)
        return alp[i]

    items = []

    for c in text:
        if c in ru_lower:
            c = get_shift(ru_lower, c, key)

        elif c in ru_upper:
            c = get_shift(ru_upper, c, key)

        items.append(c)

    return ''.join(items)

print(shifr_file_readlines('Тестирование буквы Ё'))
# Ясюяхэыомъхс начоз Т

print(shifr_file_readlines('Привет мир!', key=1))
# Рсйгёу нйс!
```

---

**UPD.**

Пример с файлами.

Например, у вас есть файл `Текст.txt` его содержимое нужно зашифровать цезарем и сохранить в `Текст_зашифрованный.txt`

```
with open("Текст.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    text = f.read()

new_text = shifr_file_readlines(text)

with open("Текст_зашифрованный.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(new_text)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105967/discussion-on-answer-by-gil9red-----).