# Возникает ошибка при запуске программы

Tags: python

Ошибка выглядит следующим образом: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: invalid continuation byte.
Моя программа выглядит так:

```
from tkinter import *
def file_readlines():
    with open("Текст2.txt", 'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        return(f.read())
def shifr_file_readlines(file_message, key):
    s1=''
    alf2 = ['а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т',
            'у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я']
    key=alf2.index(key)
    for c in file_message:
        if ord(c) in range(ord('а'), ord('я')+1): # если это символ а-я
            s1 += chr(ord('а') + (ord(c) - ord('а') + key)%33)
        elif ord(c) in range(ord('А'), ord('Я')+1): # если это символ А-Я
            s1 += chr(ord('А') + (ord(c) - ord('А') + key)%33)
        else: # иначе просто дописываем этот символ
            s1 += c
    return ''.join(s1)
p=file_readlines()
tp2=StringVar()
txt2 = Entry(root,textvariable=tp2,width=50)
btn_filelines_cezar = Button(root, text="Зашифровать многострочный файл шифром Цезаря",command=lambda: result_file_readlines(root,p,tp2.get()),
              font="Calibri 15",height=2,width=45,bg="green")
btn_filelines_cezar.place(x=0,y=390)
root.mainloop()
```

Как можно исправить?

**UPD.**

```
def shifr_file_readlines(file_message, key):
    result=[]
    alf = ['А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т',
           'У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я']
    alf2 = ['а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т',
            'у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я']
    file_message=file_message.replace("\n","")
    for i,txt in enumerate(file_message):
        if txt.isupper():
            if txt!=' ':
                mes=alf.index(txt)
                ky=alf2.index(key)
                y=(mes+ky)%33
                result.append(alf[y]+"\n")
            else:
                result.append(' ')
        else:
            if txt!=' ':
                mes=alf2.index(txt)
                ky=alf2.index(key)
                y=(mes+ky)%33
                result.append(alf2[y]+"\n")
            else:
                result.append(' ')
    return ''.join(result)
```

Comment: `with open("Текст2.txt", 'r',encoding='cp1251') as f:`

Comment: появляется такая ошибка
  File "C:\Users\Тиран\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0450' in position 3: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Ну хз: `with open("Текст2.txt", 'r',encoding='cp1252') as f:` Вы сами должны знать кодировку файла, что считывайте :) Мб там `"ISO-8859-1"` Если не знаете и ваш любимый редактор не показывает кодировку (notepad++, кст, показывает), то в цикле перебираете все кодировки пока не выйдет хороший результат. Добавьте в вопрос результат `print( open("Текст2.txt", 'rb').read() )`, глядишь кто скажет какая там кодировка

Comment: все равно не помогает, все кодировки перепробовал, та же ошибка(

Comment: Буква `ё` не входит в диапазон `а-я` в юникоде, поэтому зашифровать её с помощью `ord` не получится Так как в диапазоне `а-я` не 33, а 32 символа, то возможно из-за этого и ломается. Вообще, не надо записывать файлы в cp1251, записывайте только в utf-8

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: а как тогда можно зашифровать текст?

Comment: @Tiranich, моя реализация в предыдущем вопросе работает по другому -- через подмену, у нее нет проблем с `ё`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1099075/201445 Шифрование и расшифрование происходит с одним ключом, но с различным `+` и `-`. Т.е. например, шифровать с `key=5`, а расшифровывать с `key=-5`

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста в моем ответе

Comment: У вас тут многое плохо -- ненужный `enumerate`, ненужный список алфавита (можно просто в строке хранить все буквы), странная проверка на `' '`, а ведь в строках есть и другие символы, что не входят в алфавит -- точки, запятые, символы перевода строки и т.п. И непонятно зачем вы добавляете символ перевода строки `"\n"` **с каждым символом**. И непонятно почему игнорируете мою реализацию -- там таких проблем нет

Comment: Во-первых, ваша реализация мне непонятна, во-вторых, в исходном файле многострочный текст, для этого я пытаюсь в зашифрованном файле сохранить эту многострочность, в-третьих, проверка на '    ' нужна для текста, в котором содержатся пробелы, и если текст сплошной, то просто буквы шифруем, а если встречается пробел, то мы его добавляем в зашифрованный текст.

Comment: Моя реализация сохранит символы, что не входят в алфавит, т.е. и пробелы, и символы перевода строки, и запятые, и точки, и ее отличие в том в качестве ключа указывать значение сдвига, а не буква. У вас код ломаться будет при наличии в тексте символов, что не входят в алфавит и не пробел: `print(shifr_file_readlines('Тестирование.', key='Г'))` тут из-за точки ломает, а тут ошибка `print(shifr_file_readlines('Тестирование', key='Г'))` из-за того что вы всегда ищите индекс ключа в `alf2`, т.е. буква ключ должна быть в нижнем регистре. То, что вам непонятен код не аргумент, могли бы спросить о нем

Answer (score 0):

Дописал код из вопрос. Для расшифровки добавил флаг, т.к. ключом является буква, по которой сдвиг выполняется, а как передать отрицательный сдвиг через буквы -- вопрос.

Пример:

```
def shifr_file_readlines(file_message, key, decode=True):
    ru_lower = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
    ru_upper = ru_lower.upper()

    if key in ru_lower:
        shift = ru_lower.index(key)
    elif key in ru_upper:
        shift = ru_upper.index(key)
    else:
        raise Exception('Invalid key!')

    # Для расшифровки делаем отрицательный ключ
    if decode:
        shift = -shift

    result = []

    for c in file_message:
        if c in ru_lower:
            i = (ru_lower.index(c) + shift) % len(ru_lower)
            c = ru_lower[i]

        elif c in ru_upper:
            i = (ru_upper.index(c) + shift) % len(ru_upper)
            c = ru_upper[i]

        result.append(c)

    return ''.join(result)
```

Использование:

```
cipher_text = shifr_file_readlines('Тестирование\nБуква.Ё.\n\n123', key='Г')
print(cipher_text)
# Пвопёнляэкёв
# Юрзяэ.Г.
# 
# 123

print()

text = shifr_file_readlines(cipher_text, key='Г', decode=False)
print(text)
# Тестирование
# Буква.Ё.
# 
# 123
```